# How to read INFORMIX Table JSON Column in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I would like to read INFORMIX Table column defined as JSON in java using JDBC Call. Here is my Table Schema in INFORMIX 12.10

```
create row type fullname_t
    (
    first varchar(20),
    middle varchar(20),
    last varchar(20)
    );
create row type person_t
    (
    name fullname_t,
    age integer
    );
create row type phone_t
    (
    type varchar(10),
    contact varchar(20)
    );
create table teachers  (
id integer,
person person_t,
dept varchar(20),
hobbies LIST(varchar(255) not null),
phones LIST(phone_t not null),
address "informix".json not null  );
```

Sample Data

```
DELETE FROM teachers WHERE 1=1;
INSERT INTO teachers VALUES (100, "ROW(ROW('Bill', 'William', 'Smith'), 27)", "physics", "LIST{'Cricket', 'Soccer'}","LIST{ROW('FIXED', '08023456789'), ROW('MOBILE', '9035252525')}",'{type: "HOME", addrLine1: "123525", city: "Bangalore", zipCode: "560001", state: "KA", country: "INDIA"}'::JSON);
INSERT INTO teachers VALUES (101, "ROW(ROW('John', 'Martin', 'Smith'), 30)", "math", "LIST{'Tennis', 'Baseball'}","LIST{ROW('FIXED', '1-800-CALL-SUPPORT')}",'{type: "HOME", addrLine1: "51st A cross 5th Main", city: "Chennai", zipCode: "909404", state: "TN", country: "INDIA"}'::JSON);
```

I am able to read Custom ROW Type(s) like person, phones except for address which is JSON type.

Appreciate any help / advice to read JSON object as String and subsequently, I can get Jackson API to convert JSON String.

Requires custom SQLData map, but not sure how to do for JSON

Output from JDBC Select

```
Teacher [id=100, person=Person [name=Fullname [first=Bill, middle=William, last=Smith], age=27], dept=physics, hobbies=[Cricket, Soccer], phones=[Phone [type=FIXED, contact=08023456789], Phone [type=MOBILE, contact=9035252525]], address=null]
Teacher [id=101, person=Person [name=Fullname [first=John, middle=Martin, last=Smith], age=30], dept=math, hobbies=[Tennis, Baseball], phones=[Phone [type=FIXED, contact=1-800-CALL-SUPPORT]], address=null]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the location of your Informix JDBC Driver installation (version 4.10 , not sure about previous versions) you should have a "demo/bson/" directory with a demo java program that should help in explaining how to handle the informix bson and json datatypes: [Examples in the bson directory](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_514.htm?lang=en)

**EDIT 1:**

I created the following table and inserted some values. I used `BSON` type but we can just cast to `JSON` and vice-versa:

```
CREATE TABLE
(
    id SERIAL
  , stuff BSON
);

INSERT INTO myspace values (0, '{"val1" : "123", "val2" : "uno"}'::JSON::BSON);
INSERT INTO myspace values (0, '{"val1" : "456", "val2" : "duo"}'::JSON::BSON);
INSERT INTO myspace values (0, '{"val1" : "879", "val2" : "trio"}'::JSON::BSON);
INSERT INTO myspace values (0, '{"val1" : "987", "val2" : "quad"}'::JSON::BSON);


SELECT id, stuff::JSON AS stuff FROM myspace;

id     1
stuff  {"val1":"123","val2":"uno"}

id     2
stuff  {"val1":"456","val2":"duo"}

id     3
stuff  {"val1":"789","val2":"trio"}

id     4
stuff  {"val1":"987","val2":"quad"}
```

Modifying the demo java program (sorry about the ugly code):

```
IfxDataSource ifxDs = null;
Connection conn1 = null;
Statement stmt1 = null;
IfxResultSet rs = null; 
IfxBSONObject bsonObject = null;

try
{
    // Create a DataSource instance
    System.out.println("INFO: create DataSource");
    ifxDs = new IfxDataSource();
    ifxDs.setServerName("MYIFXSERVER");
    ifxDs.setDatabaseName("doluis");
    ifxDs.setIfxIFXHOST("192.168.56.101");
    ifxDs.setPortNumber(15000);
    ifxDs.setUser("YYYYY");
    ifxDs.setPassword("XXXXXXX");

    // get connection
    System.out.println("INFO: Get connection");
    conn1 = ifxDs.getConnection();            
    System.out.println("INFO: Database version  ..... : " + conn1.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion());
    System.out.println("INFO: JDBC Driver Version ... : " + IfxDriver.getJDBCVersion());


    try
    {
        // Create a Statement
        stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();

        // Do some DML
        System.out.println("INFO:  myspace");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM myspace";
        System.out.println("INFO: [QUERY] " + sql);
        rs = (IfxResultSet) stmt1.executeQuery(sql);

        int i = 1;          
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            //* get the BSON object using informix extension to PreparedStatement.
            bsonObject = rs.getIfxBSONObject("stuff"); 
            //* calling IfxBSONObject.toString() to deserialize the object for readable string;
            System.out.println("INFO: [RESULT:" + i + "] id:" + rs.getInt("id") + " | stuff:" + bsonObject.toString());
            Map<String, Object> map = bsonObject.toMap();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println("\t" +"key:value -> " +entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
            }
            i++;
        }
        // Close result set and stmt1 
        rs.close();
        stmt1.close();
        // Create a Statement
        stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();

        // Do some DML
        System.out.println("INFO:  myspace");
        sql = "SELECT id, stuff::JSON AS stuff FROM myspace";
        System.out.println("INFO: [QUERY] " + sql);
        rs = (IfxResultSet) stmt1.executeQuery(sql);

        i = 1;          
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            // Columns stuff was casted to JSON, we can get it as a string
            System.out.println("INFO: [RESULT:" + i + "] id:" + rs.getInt("id") + " | stuff:" + rs.getString("stuff"));
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlex)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR: Code : " + sqlex.getErrorCode() + ", Message : " + sqlex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        rs.close();
        rs = null;                
        stmt1.close();
        stmt1 = null;                
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("FAILED: upps, something went wrong");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if (conn1 != null)
    {
        try
        {
            conn1.close();
            conn1 = null;
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlex)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR: Code : " + sqlex.getErrorCode() + ", Message : " + sqlex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And i get the following output:

```
INFO: create DataSource
INFO: Get connection
INFO: Database version  ..... : 12.10.FC6DE
INFO: JDBC Driver Version ... : 4.10.JC6DE
INFO:  myspace
INFO: [QUERY] SELECT * FROM myspace
INFO: [RESULT:1] id:1 | stuff:IfxBSONObject { "val1" : "123" , "val2" : "uno" }
    key:value -> val1:123
    key:value -> val2:uno
INFO: [RESULT:2] id:2 | stuff:IfxBSONObject { "val1" : "456" , "val2" : "duo" }
    key:value -> val1:456
    key:value -> val2:duo
INFO: [RESULT:3] id:3 | stuff:IfxBSONObject { "val1" : "789" , "val2" : "trio" }
    key:value -> val1:789
    key:value -> val2:trio
INFO: [RESULT:4] id:4 | stuff:IfxBSONObject { "val1" : "987" , "val2" : "quad" }
    key:value -> val1:987
    key:value -> val2:quad
INFO:  myspace
INFO: [QUERY] SELECT id, stuff::JSON AS stuff FROM myspace
INFO: [RESULT:1] id:1 | stuff:{"val1":"123","val2":"uno"}
INFO: [RESULT:2] id:2 | stuff:{"val1":"456","val2":"duo"}
INFO: [RESULT:3] id:3 | stuff:{"val1":"789","val2":"trio"}
INFO: [RESULT:4] id:4 | stuff:{"val1":"987","val2":"quad"}
```

So, the `toString()` method from the IfxBSONObject appends the `IfxBSONObject` string, which seems weird, but maybe you can still use it. Or you can modify the map part to produce the output you require.
Or maybe it is just simpler to cast to `JSON` and get the value from the result set as a string.
In your case, since you already use `JSON`, you can just retrieve it as a string.

Comment: Thanks Luis, will install and look into it.

Comment: Though I used the example, still I am unable to get JSON data as string as mentioned in the example.

Comment: @Anand i added a code example based on the demo. Maybe it can help.